# Kinds of thermal paste

Tags: heatsink

I want to replace thermal paste in my notebook computer. I disassembled a cooling system. There are 2 kinds of thermal paste:

1. A "normal" paste on CPU.
2. Like a plasticine on chipset and GPU.

Can someone explain me what is the second? What is it called?

Comment: I've use thermal paste on both. I have had experience with OC GPU's not liking the thermal pads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter is a [**thermal pad**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermally_conductive_pad). It doesn't need to be spread like thermal grease and so is easier to apply and contain, but is slightly less effective at conducting heat.